# postgresql install on lubuntu 14.04 -i386

Tags: lubuntu, software-center, postgresql

Got a version of Ubuntu (lubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-i386) to install and behave on this HP Pavilion dv5 and was able to install Libre Office via Lubuntu Software Center.  Progress.

My next task is to install Postgresql 9.4.  I expected to find it in Software Center, but only see PgAdmin.  Which is good cause I need pgAdmin also.

1. Should I see Postgresql in the Lubuntu software center?
   As per the Postgresql site it can be installed by using:  apt-get install postgresql-9.4     When I execute this command I get: Permission Denied  then are you root?  No I am not logged in as root.
2. The lubuntu install never asked anything about a root password.  How do I login as root?  I do need to login as root once-and-a-while.
3. The big question:  How do I install Postgresql 9.4 on this Lubuntu machine?

Many thanks for your attention to this matter?

KD

Answer (score 0):

You may install PostgreSQL 9.4 with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4
```

Comment: Learn to use the edit button to edit your own answers next time (yes you have that kind of access to edit your own answer)